# How to replace the first character of all keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python

What is the best way to replace the first character of all keys in a dictionary?

```
old_cols= {"~desc1":"adjustment1","~desc23":"adjustment3"}
```

I am trying to get

```
new_cols= {"desc1":"adjustment1","desc23":"adjustment3"}
```

I have tried:

```
for k,v in old_cols.items():
    new_cols[k]=old_cols.pop(k[1:])
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? "Best way" in what sense?

Answer (score 2):

```py
old_cols = {"~desc1":"adjustment1", "~desc23":"adjustment3"}
new_cols = {}

for k, v in old_cols.items():
    new_key = k[1:] 
    new_cols[new_key] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with a dictionary comprehension:

```
old_cols= {"~desc1":"adjustment1","~desc23":"adjustment3"}

new_cols = {k.replace('~', ''):old_cols[k] for k in old_cols}

print(new_cols)
#{'desc1': 'adjustment1', 'desc23': 'adjustment3'}
```

Comment: Won't work properly if a key contains more than one tilde character

Comment: @Kolay.Ne. Meets OP's requirements.   There is no indication that the keys have more than on tilde.

Comment: @papke, disagreed. OP said nothing about tildes at all. The question was about removing the first element from the keys

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with list-comprehension or `for`-loops. What is important is to understand is that dictionaries are mutable. This basically means that you can either modify the existing dictionary or create a new one.

If you want to create a new one (and I would recommend it! - see *'A word of warning ...'* below), both solutions provided in the answers [by @Ethem_Turgut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830925/1622937) and [by @pakpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830878/1622937) do the trick. I would probably wirte:

```py
old_dict = {"~desc1":"adjustment1","~desc23":"adjustment3"}
# get the id of this dict, just for comparison later.
old_id = id(old_dict)

new_dict = {k[1:]: v for k, v in old_dict.items()}

print(f'Is the result still the same dictionary? Answer: {old_id == id(new_dict)}')
```

Now, if you want to modify the dictionary in place you might loop over the keys and adapt the key/value to your liking:

```py
old_dict = {"~desc1":"adjustment1","~desc23":"adjustment3"}
# get the id of this dict, just for comparison later.
old_id = id(old_dict)

for k in [*old_dict.keys()]:  # note the weird syntax here
    old_dict[k[1:]] = old_dict.pop(k)

print(f'Is the result still the same dictionary? Answer: {old_id == id(old_dict)}')
```

#### A word of warning for the latter approach:

You should be aware that you are modifying the keys while looping over them. This is in most of the cases problematic and can even lead to a `RuntimeError` if you loop directly over `old_dict`. I avoided this by explicitly unpacking the keys into a list and the looping over that list with `[*old_dict.keys()]`.

Why can modifying keys while looping over them be problematic? Imagine for example that you have the keys `'~key1'` and `'key1'` in your `old_dict`. Now when your loop handles `'~key1'` it will modify it to `'key1'` which already exists in `old_dict` and thus it will overwrite the value of `'key1'` with the value from `'~key1'`.

So, only use the latter approach if you are certain to not produce issues like the example mentioned here before. If you are uncertain, simply create a new dictionary!

Comment: "If you want to create a new one (and I would recommend it!)"
Why do you recommend it?

Comment: @Kolay.Ne it avoids the potential issues mentioned in the *A word of warning for the latter approach*. But there might be situations where it makes sense to modify a dictionary in place, it really depends.

Comment: oh, sorry, I haven't read the answer completely. I thought what you recommended was not to "create new dictionary object instead of modifying the old one", but to not do `old_dict = {... for k, v in old_dict.items()}` (save the result of `old_dict` modification to the same variable)

Comment: @Kolay.Ne with respect to the question whether or not you create a new dictionary, it does not matter if you refer the result to a new variable, like `new_dict` or back to `old_dict`, in both cases you have created a new dictionary. You can check this by simply replacing `new_dict` with `old_dict` in the first case. The print statement will still print `False`.

Comment: @Kolay.Ne what does change if you reuse `old_dict` instead of a new varaible, however, is that the initial dictionary the variable `old_dict` referred to is not longer referenced and thus might get deleted.